# Factor out factorial from expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, factorial

I have the expression $(k+1)! - 1 + (k+1)(k+1)!$

How do I factor out $(k+1)!$ to achieve the result: $[(k+1)!(k+2)] - 1$?

I for the life of me cannot figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a statement - you need an equality to have a statement.  Right now, you only have an expression.

Comment: Oops, not sure what to call it. A line?

Comment: Note $a+ba = (1+b)a$  Here, use $a=(k+1)!$ and $b=(k+1)$

Comment: Hint: Write $y=(k+1)!$, then you have $y+(k+1)y-1$.  Then factor a $y$ from the first two terms to get $y[1+(k+1)]-1=y(k+2)-1$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That makes perfect sense! For some reason I did not realize I could forget about the -1. Duh!